# DataTables problems PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use DataTables server side with the following codes:

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready( function () {

            $('#table').DataTable({
                "serverSide": true,
                "processing": true,
                "ajax": "{{ $url }}",

                "aoColumns": [
                    { "data": null },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "playercount" },
                    { "data": "warswon" },
                    { "data": "warslost" },
                    { "data": "warstied" },
                    { "data": "level"},
                    { "data": "exp"},
                    { "data": "location"},
                    { "data": "warwinpercent"}
                ],

                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                    $('td:eq(1)', nRow).html('<a href="/clans/' + aData[1] + '">' +
                            aData[3] + '</a>');
                    return nRow;
                },

                "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
                    var index = iDisplayIndex + 1;
                    $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(index);
                    return nRow;
                }
            });

            $('#table').dataTable().columnFilter({
                sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                aoColumns: [null, { type: "text" }, null, null, null, null, null, null, { type: "text" }, null]
            });

        } );
    </script>
```

And my PHP code for server processing is available here: http://pastebin.com/Wpn9u64U

You can see my live example at: http://clashdata.tk/clans/

The problems are:

- It is only showing me 10 records.
- Pagination doesn't working.
- Search filtering doesn't working.
- Order by doesn't work.

What is going on and how come these aren't working as they should?

I've been searching around but can't find anything. Someone said to set serverSide to false but the whole point of this is to use serverSide so I don't have to mass load data on page load.

Here is the serverCode in the post:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\DataTables;

use PDO;
use PDOException;

ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);


class DataTables {

    private $_db;

    public function __construct() {

        try {
            $host               = 'localhost';
            $database           = 'zzzzzzzzzzzz';
            $user               = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
            $passwd             = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy';

            $this->_db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $user, $passwd, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log("Failed to connect to database: ".$e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function utf8ize($d) {
        if (is_array($d)) {
            foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
                $d[$k] = $this->utf8ize($v);
            }
        } else if (is_string ($d)) {
            return utf8_encode($d);
        }
        return $d;
    }

    public function get($table, $index_column, $columns) {

        // Paging
        $sLimit = "";
        if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' ) {
            $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
        }

        // Ordering
        $sOrder = "";
        if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) ) {
            $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ ) {
                if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" ) {
                    $sortDir = (strcasecmp($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i], 'ASC') == 0) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
                    $sOrder .= "`".$columns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` ". $sortDir .", ";
                }
            }

            $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
            if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" ) {
                $sOrder = "";
            }
        }

        /*
         * Filtering
         * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
         * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
         * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
         */
        $sWhere = "";
        if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" ) {
            $sWhere = "WHERE (";
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
                if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" ) {
                    $sWhere .= "`".$columns[$i]."` LIKE :search OR ";
                }
            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
            $sWhere .= ')';
        }

        // Individual column filtering
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' ) {
                if ( $sWhere == "" ) {
                    $sWhere = "WHERE ";
                }
                else {
                    $sWhere .= " AND ";
                }
                $sWhere .= "`".$columns[$i]."` LIKE :search".$i." ";
            }
        }

        // SQL queries get data to display

        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SET @rownum = 0');
        $stmt->execute();

        $sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $columns))."`, @rownum := @rownum+1 AS rank FROM `".$table."` ".$sWhere." ".$sOrder." ".$sLimit;
        $statement = $this->_db->prepare($sQuery);

        // Bind parameters
        if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" ) {
            $statement->bindValue(':search', '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' ) {
                $statement->bindValue(':search'.$i, '%'.$_GET['sSearch_'.$i].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }

        $statement->execute();
        $rResult = $statement->fetchAll();

        $iFilteredTotal = current($this->_db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetch());

        // Get total number of rows in table
        $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(`".$index_column."`) FROM `".$table."`";
        $iTotal = current($this->_db->query($sQuery)->fetch());

        // Output
        $output = array(
            "draw" => 1,
            "recordsTotal" => $iTotal,
            "recordsFiltered" => $iFilteredTotal,
            "data" => array()
        );

        // Return array of values
        foreach($rResult as $aRow) {
            $row = array();
            for ( $i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++ ) {
                if ( $columns[$i] == "version" ) {
                    // Special output formatting for 'version' column
                    $row[] = ($aRow[ $columns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $columns[$i] ];
                }
                else if ( $columns[$i] != ' ' ) {
                    $row[] = $aRow[ $columns[$i] ];
                }
            }
            $output['data'][] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($this->utf8ize($output));
    }

}

header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');

// Create instance of TableData class
$tableData = new DataTables();
$tableData->get('clans', 'id', array('id', 'clanid', 'name'));

?>
```

***UPDATE***

I've just noticed that the link the console is fetching new data on when paginating displays the correct data but that data isn't getting put onto the table.

Comment: please post the relevant server side script code here.

Comment: All of the server code on pastebin is relevant because I have no idea where I am going wrong @devlincarnate I am adding the code in my post as well.

Comment: well, start debugging. figure out WHERE you only get 10 values from. check the raw data coming from your php script? Are there more than 10 records there? Then it's something in your JS code. otherwise it's a server-side problem.

Comment: Check your console for script errors, post please, your query as well.

Comment: @MarcB I have no idea. How can I even find what the exact script it is calling is with the GET parameters?

Comment: @Kisaragi the console shows no errors.

Comment: get params? Those'd be visible in your server's access log.

Comment: @ShivamPaw - I can't access pastebin.  Please post the code here.

Comment: @devlincarnate I've posted it.

Comment: Looking at your page, It looks like your issue will most certainly be the data source.

Comment: @Kisaragi then cna you check the code and see where it is going wrong?

Comment: @Kisaragi If I make the URLs manually I am getting the correct results returned from the data source. But there's no way to get them working with DataTables...

Comment: I've just noticed that the link the console is fetching new data on when paginating displays the correct data but that data isn't getting put onto the table.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your php code, you are LIMITing the query with

```
$sLimit = "LIMIT 0, 100";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' ) {
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}
```

But, looking at the ajax call's parameter, you should read page and page_length from:

> length    -  10
>
> start   -  0

So, your code should look like this

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 'value';");
$rows = array();
foreach($result AS $row){
    $rows[] = array(/*save your desired fields*/);
}
//sort them as you need
$iTotalRecords = $result->rowCount();
$iDisplayLength = intval($_REQUEST['length']);
$iDisplayStart = intval($_REQUEST['start']);
$iDisplayLength = $iDisplayLength < 0 ? $iTotalRecords : $iDisplayLength;
$end = $iDisplayStart + $iDisplayLength;
$end = $end > $iTotalRecords ? $iTotalRecords : $end;
$output = array(
    "draw" => 1,
    "recordsTotal" => $iTotal,
    "recordsFiltered" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "data" => array()
);
for($i = $iDisplayStart; $i < $end; $i++) {
    $output["data"][] = array(/*your table columns here*/);
}
$output["draw"] = $_REQUEST['draw'];
$output["recordsTotal"] = $iTotalRecords;
$output["recordsFiltered"] = $iTotalRecords;
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: I fixed this some time ago though. I remove the `limit 0, 100`

Comment: I don't know if your live example is up to date, but it gets stuck when trying to change page or to sort by column

Comment: There's an error in your JS. When you click on other page, it makes an ajax call to the wrong url.